# Will search engines index the content of PDF loaded with XHR by PDF.js?

Tags: seo, pdf

I'm using the [PDF.js viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).  After the page loads, it executes an XHR to get the PDF.

Will the contents of the PDF be indexed by search engines like Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is their demo:  https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

The contents of the demo are indexed in Google:

[image]